# Blazor compiling time

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently working on an ERP Blazor project comprising approximately 1800 Blazor components. However, the compilation process is noticeably time-consuming.

To pinpoint the source of the issue, I decided to create a simplified Blazor server project with 5,000 components, each containing only the content `<h1>Hi!</h1>`. The compilation time for this project in my Windows is as follows:

```
C:\tmp\blazorslow> dotnet build
MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\tmp\blazorslow\blazorslow.csproj (in 1.59 sec).
  blazorslow -> C:\tmp\blazorslow\bin\Debug\net8.0\blazorslow.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:06:18.73
```

If instead of `.razor` I use c# code components (classes inheriting from `ComponentBase`), it takes 16 seconds.

Given these circumstances, I am prompted to inquire about the readiness of Blazor for real-world projects. Moreover, I am keen to explore potential solutions to expedite the compilation process. The current challenge lies in the fact that even a minor modification, such as changing "Hi!" to "Hello," triggers a 6-minute compilation time.

The question: Can I improve, in some way, compilation time for projects with hundreds of `.razor` files? Thanks.

Notice: On my apple M1 compiling time is less than 2 minutes (but also is a lot of time for that simple project)

**Edited**

After reading `@ℍ ℍ`'s comment, which mentioned, "I estimate the growth at about O(n^2),", I have compiled the following table. Additionally, I observed that after restarting my work PC, the processing time decreased; however, the pattern still resembles Polynomial Time behavior:

| n | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 00:00:08.03 |
| 2000 | 00:00:28.79 |
| 3000 | 00:00:38.82 |
| 4000 | 00:00:58.11 |
| 5000 | 00:01:37.39 |
| 6000 | 00:02:06.63 |
| 7000 | 00:02:57.10 |
| 8000 | 00:04:13.81 |
| 9000 | 00:04:58.08 |
| 10000 | 00:06:37.49 |

[image: Viz of previous table]

Comment: Can't you separate the components in different assemblies so that you only need to compile the assembly with modified ones?

Comment: Hi @Jcl, It's not a solution, but right now, it's the only way I have to alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are hundreds of components in 1 project then they all have to be recompiled each time. There is no memory.

A structural approach would be to split the UI into multiple (RCL) projects. A change should normally only affect 1 project.

But as a fun experiment, could you turn on `<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>` and see what changing 1 file does then?  I wonder if MsBuild recognizes when a `.g.razor.cs` file is newer than the `.razor` file and skips that compiler step.

Comment: Looks like a clever idea. I will try tomorrow. I will come back with some news.

Comment: I ran a few tests and the generated files don't help. Maybe with adapted build targets but I doubt it.

Comment: I estimate the growth at about O(n^2).   1000 components is quite doable, beyond 2000 it gets bad. So splitting into a handful of RCLs should make it workable.

Comment: Hi HH, after conducting some tests, I can confirm that it exhibits Polynomial Time behavior. I believe this is a crucial factor to consider when planning Blazor projects, especially for large-scale ERPs. This should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @daniherrera it's hardly surprising to me that the razor transpiler would be slow... splitting in RCLs would be wise anyway (even if just because I'm quite sure those thousands of components are probably not that coupled in their domain)... I'd probably just not have thousands of classes in a single assembly either (razor or not razor). Just out of curiosity: does hot reload work fine (speed wise, not talking about functionality) in your case?

Comment: Hi @Jcl, I disabled hot reload in its early versions because it didn't work for medium/large projects. I've never dared to turn it back on. Does it work for you?

Comment: @daniherrera I've never done HUGE blazor server projects (just some small and middle). It "kinda worked" but had many caveats (functionallity-wise). Didn't use it very much ever, but I was curious about the speed on your big project

Comment: @Jcl in terms of performance, Blazor server runs like a charm. If your client connection is stable, it's a good choice. If your users use the mobile app and they are going to go through tunnels, then it's not your product.

Comment: @ℍℍ I posted this like an issue https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/9714 

Comment: @daniherrera oh yes, I love Blazor server (for its use cases, where it fits). Was talking about compilation and hot-reload performance only (not runtime performance). The "kinda worked" and the rest of my comment was referring to hot-reload specifically